# Typescript autocomplete

Tags: typescript, autocomplete

I have some problems with autocompletion in my code. The main idea is to enable autocompletion when I use a factory class for create objects:

```
class Test1 {
    method1(){}
}
class Test2 {
    method2(){}
}
class Test_Factory {
    create(type) {
        if (type === "test1") {
            return new Test1()
        } else if (type === "test2") {
            return new Test2()
        }
    }
}
let factory1 = new Test_Factory()
let tst1 = factory1.create("test1")
tst1. // autocomplite not work
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning multiple types so typescript won't know what exactly is the type, so you should cast the return value to the expected type to have the intellisense working correctly.

```
let tst1 = factory1.create('test1') as Test1;
```

or

```
let tst1 = <Test1>factory1.create('test1');
```